# Why it is more accurate to evaluate $x^2-y^2$ as $(x+y)(x-y)$ in floating point system?

Tags: numerical-methods

The expression $x^2-y^2$ exhibits **catastrophic cancellation** if $|x|\approx|y|$. 
Why it is more accurate to evaluate as $(x+y)(x-y)$ in floating point system (like IEEE 754)? I see this is intuitively true. Any one can help demonstrate an example when $|x|\approx|y|$? And is there any (or how to write) a formal proof for the claim?

A detailed explanation would be very much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: $$x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$$ is more accurate if you use $|x|=|y|$ you can lose solutions in an equation

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Could you explain a little more why the latter is more accurate? Thanks!

Comment: You do one multiplication versus two. Multiplication is less stable than addition due to the mixing of digits.

Comment: Read David Goldberg's classic paper [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each single elementary operation has a truncation error of at most $1/2$ ulp (unit in the last place), which is about a relative error of less than $\mu=2^{-53}$. Let's express the floating point realizations of the two expressions using these relative errors $|δ_i|\le \mu$.

The errors are
\begin{align}
fl(fl(x^2)-fl(y^2))&=(x^2(1+δ_1)-y^2(1+δ_2))(1+δ_3)
\\
&=(x^2-y^2)+x^2δ_1-y^2δ_2+(x^2-y^2)δ_3+\text{higher order terms}
\end{align}
which has as first order upper bound $[x^2+y^2+|x^2-y^2|]\mu=2\max(x^2,y^2)\mu$, and
$$
fl(fl(x+y)fl(x-y))=((x+y)(1+δ_1)\,(x-y)(1+δ_2))(1+δ_3)
$$
where the upper bound for the first order terms is $3 |x^2-y^2| μ$.

---

To demonstrate that this calculation is indeed reflected in actual floating point arithmetic, consider $x\in [1,2]$ and $y=x+ε$ with $ε$ fixed to some small value, here $\varepsilon=7\cdot 2^{-m}$ for some $m$ in the upper range of the mantissa length. Then the exact difference is $2εx+ε^2$. The error bound for the first formula now appears as $2x^2\mu$ and for the second formula as $6xε\mu$.

The plots show that the derived error bounds are valid and rather tight for both formulas, the error of the second formula is only really visible in the logarithmic plot and is zero for all practical purposes.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! May I ask what is $\mu$? Is it $\max(\delta_1, \delta_2, \delta3)$? Thank you!

Comment: No, it is the fixed (relative) machine precision, $\mu=2^{-53}$ for the `double` floating point numbers. Thus $|δ_k|\le μ$.

Comment: Fantastic answer!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer is when $x$ and $y$ are large, $x^2$ and $y^2$ are larger. If they are of the same order of magnitude then when you consider evaluating $x^2 - y^2$ you are taking away two large numbers and the round off error will be larger than if you write it is $(x + y) (x - y)$. For $x \approx y$, the second approach gives $\approx 2x \times (x-y)$. Hope that helps.